# C# How to get loading status of one window in another window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window

I'm writing a program in wpf with c# that contains two windows. One named `MainWindow` and the other named `SubWindow`.

The MainWindow contains a button and a textblock. When the button is clicked SubWindow is shown.

SubWindow contains several images and videos (MediaElement) embeded into it from image and video files on the disk. So when the SubWindow is loading it also loads the images and videos from the disk. This takes a while.
So I want the user to know the the file names of the image and video files that are being currently loaded in SubWindow. I want to achieve this by showing the file names that are being loaded in the textblock in MainWindow. To sum up, when the button on MainWindow is clicked the SubWindow loads and the textblock in MainWindow shows the filename of the file that is currently being loaded in the SubWindow and once all the files are loaded the textblock shows the message "all files loaded successfully". How do I achieve this?

Comment: There are already [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063550/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840214/) about how to pass data between WPF components. [Use events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635374/); it is very problematic to pass UI components between classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use events.

to register a new event, put the below code to your sub window on top

```
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Action")]
        public event EventHandler<string> MyFilesLoaded;
```

when your code loads the files raise the event like this. You can raise the event as many times you like.

```
  string f = "abc.doc,123.xls";
  EventHandler<string> handler = MyFilesLoaded;
  handler?.Invoke(null, f);
```

of course instead of string you can pass a list.

At your main window register the event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    SubWindow.MyFilesLoaded+= DoSomething;
}
```

And handle the event when fired:

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, string files)
{
     mynicetxt.Text = files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the main window into the sub-window constructor, this gives you access to all elements on the main window. Including any methods you have written to, say, update a textbox.

I also think there is a "parent" property you can traverse back to find the main windows? I don't remember clearly however, if that is the case?

Comment: But how do I know what file is currently being loaded?

Comment: your sub-window knows which file it is at surely? The method doing the loading, know what it is doing?

For a nice an neat implementation you could use an observer pattern, that might be a bit overkill however?